# How to control the bit type of a python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am using a 64 bit machine (therefore python 2.7 for 64 bit) but wanted to explore PyAudio which was intended for 32 bit machines.

How do I now control the bit type of python files. Like when I write a new python program how do I specify whether the 32 bit or 64 bit version of python should be used to interpret it?

After doing some fairly thorough looking I don't see an option that I can check or know of a file extension I can use to differentiate the two types

Comment: The *compiler* produces 32 or 64-bit binaries. This has really nothing to do with Python; PyAudio uses C extensions and if you download pre-compiled binaries for those you get one or the other.

Comment: So upon testing a random python program I made the computer immediately picked up that it was teh x86 variety and properly played the tones. How did it know to do this. Since I have been default using the x64 variety of python shouldn't windows have thrown an error of some type when I tried to run this program?

Comment: How do you know your Python is not 32-bit? Windows can support either.

Comment: I installed both versions. The first copy was 64 bit, have been using it for about 1 year. Just installed the 32 bit version today to use pyaudio

Comment: If I use the 64 bit python's IDLE to make the EXACT same program I just ran the program fails claiming it is missing modules (since PyAudio is only supposed to be compatible with 32 bit versions)

Comment: I see that [Christoph Gohlke has a 64-bit version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) for you.